# Magento Config variable in CMS Block with break lines

Tags: magento, configuration, static-block

I'm wanting to use the store address within a CMS Block on a Magento website, however the problem is the line breaks are not formatted with the below:

```
{{config path="general/store_information/address"}}
```

Previously in the template we have used:

```
nl2br(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/address'));
```

The above worked fine, but we would like to move away from the template restriction.

Is there a possible way to add line breaks/formatting to the configuration variable when its pulled through in a CMS Block. In the configuration the address is entered with line breaks.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to work for me:

```
<pre>{{config path="general/store_information/address"}}</pre>
```

After that, just modify your styles to requirements.

Comment: I recommend adding this to the CSS file (perhaps under `address`): `pre      { font-family:inherit; font-style:normal; margin-bottom:5px;}`